# Problema con AJAX - jQuery - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

estoy teniendo un problema con el siguiente código:

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="stockProducto[]" id="stock_CCB" class="form-control" placeholder="Stock" required>
<input type="text" name="stockProducto[]" id="stock_SSC" class="form-control" placeholder="Stock" required>
```

ajax

```
var idProducto= 1;
var sucursales= 2;
$.ajax({
  url: 'consultas.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {idProducto,sucursales},
  success:function(data){

  }
})
```

consultas.php

```
if (isset($_POST['idProducto'])) {
  $idProducto = $_POST['idProducto'];
  $sucursales = $_POST['sucursales'];
  for ($i=0; $i < $sucursales; $i++) {
    $Q_Sucursales=mysqli_query($MySQLi,"SELECT * FROM sucursales WHERE estado=1 LIMIT $i,1 ");
    $dataSucur= mysqli_fetch_assoc($Q_Sucursales);
    $sucursal = $dataSucur['codeTienda'];
    $Q_StockPr= mysqli_query($MySQLi,"SELECT stock FROM inventario WHERE idProducto='$idProducto' LIMIT $i,1 ");
    $dataStock= mysqli_fetch_assoc($Q_StockPr);
    $stock    = $dataStock['stock'];
    $Respuesta= array('codigoTienda'=>'stock_'.$sucursal,'stockTienda'=>$stock);
    echo json_encode($Respuesta);
  }
}
```

Resputa JSON

```
{"codigoTienda":"stock_CCB","stockTienda":"9"}{"codigoTienda":"stock_SSC","stockTienda":"25"}
```

Quiero insertar la respuesta en los inputs con sus recpecivos ID, ya probe varias formas y no obtengo el resultado, alguien que me ayude?
Aquí esta el código que intenté:

```
var idProducto= 1;
var sucursales= 2;
$.ajax({
  url: 'consultas.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {idProducto,sucursales},
  success:function(data){
    $("#"+data.codigoTienda).val(data.stockTienda)
  }
})
```

Tambien inserté un bucle for a la funcion y nada, ayuda por favor.

Comment: hay que llamar JSON.parse() antes de usarlo como objecto.

Comment: Respuesta JSON= {"codigoTienda":"stock_CCB","stockTienda":"9"}{"codigoTienda":"stock_SSC","stockTienda":"25"}
.always(function(data){
 for (var i = 0; i < sucursales; i++) {
  var codTienda = JSON.parse(data.codigoTienda[i]);
  var stockTienda = JSON.parse(data.stockTienda[i]);
  console.log(codTienda);
  console.log(stockTienda);
 }
})
nada, no se como usarlo en realidad ;(

Comment: success: function(data) { laRespuesta = JSON.parse(data); console.log(laRespuesta.stockTienda[0]) }   Algo como así.

Comment: Ya probé de esa manera y no me funciona

Comment: Tal vez es laRespuesta[0].codigoTienda ?  Se me olvidó la sintaxis para una arregla de objectos.

Answer (score 0):

al parecer el error es que estas recibiendo un `Array` por parte del post.

Que significa?

```
array(
  "object" => {
      "key" => "value"
  }
);
```

Por lo tanto para acceder a la informacion tienes que hacer un ciclo que extraiga cada uno de los valores que se encuentran dentro del arreglo, puedes usar varias formas como `forEach` o `for`, Yo utilizare la primera opcion

```
success:function(data){
  data.forEach(function(element){
     $("#"+element.codigoTienda).val(element.stockTienda)
  })
}
```

Comentame si te funciono el codigo!